# How to optimise this psudocode block into loops?

Tags: javascript, sudoku

I'm trying to group a sudoku grid into the 9 boxes. I have arrayed the columns and rows but cannot think of an efficient way to code the box array.
The pseudo I'm looking at is this:

```
        add rowArray0 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray0
        add rowArray1 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray0
        add rowArray2 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray0

        add rowArray0 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray1
        add rowArray1 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray1
        add rowArray2 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray1

        add rowArray0 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray2
        add rowArray1 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray2
        add rowArray2 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray2

        add rowArray3 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray3
        add rowArray4 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray3
        add rowArray5 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray3

        add rowArray3 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray4
        add rowArray4 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray4
        add rowArray5 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray4

        add rowArray3 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray5
        add rowArray4 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray5
        add rowArray5 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray5

        add rowArray6 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray6
        add rowArray7 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray6
        add rowArray8 entries 0,1,2 to boxArray6

        add rowArray6 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray7
        add rowArray7 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray7
        add rowArray8 entries 3,4,5 to boxArray7

        add rowArray6 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray8
        add rowArray7 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray8
        add rowArray8 entries 6,7,8 to boxArray8
```

I'm sorry if this seems like a dumb question, I'm just not smart enough to figure the loop equivalent.
Someone clever can show me a solution?

Edit to add row and column array structure:

```
<table>
<tr class="r0">
<td contenteditable="true" class="c0" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">1</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c1" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">2</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c2" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">3</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c3" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">4</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c4" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">5</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c5" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">6</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c6" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">7</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c7" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">8</td>
<td contenteditable="true" class="c8" onkeyup="inputFilter(this)">9</td>
</tr>
<tr class="r1">
etc

<script>
        //columns
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            str = "c" + i;
            allCols[i] = document.getElementsByClassName(str);
        }

        //rows
        for(i=0;i<9;i++){
            rowArray = new Array();
            for(ii=0;ii<9;ii++){
                colArray = allCols[ii];
                elem = colArray[i];
                rowArray[ii] = elem;
            }
            allRows[i] = rowArray;
        }
```

So cols are top to bottom, left to right.
Rows are left to right, top to bottom.
To the comment regarding necessity of multiple arrays - wouldn't this be the best way to reference each structure? I guess I could use math each time to locate html elements however it seems logical to group them into arrays at init... maybe I'm wrong?
I guess it was a reaction to how getElementsByClassName grouped into an array. I could unpack them into single dimension arrays although why?

Comment: how is this related to javascript?

Comment: Could you post the structure of your rowArrays and the desired output in boxArrays please

Comment: Are you trying to come up with an efficient data structure to represent your Sudoku grid? If that's the case, step away from the implementation for a second and think about in which ways you will need to access/change the fields. Do you really need multiple arrays?

Comment: edited to include additional info and reply to question regarding necessity of arrays...

Answer (score 0):

A clear separation of the underlying data model from its representation is always useful.

- A sudoku can be thought of as a matrix of 9 x 9 numbers. A matrix can be represented as a flat array of 9 x 9 elements by concatenating its columns or rows into a long one-dimensional sequence. If you plan to implement a sudoku generator or solver, you probably want to chose a format compatible to a linear algebra library.
- A visual representation of a sudoku then usually includes the numbers arranged into 3 x 3 blocks in a 9 x 9 table.

A simple non-interactive example:

```js
function getNumberAt(numbers, x, y) {
  return numbers[x + 9 * y];
}

function setNumberAt(numbers, x, y, value) {
  return numbers[x + 9 * y] = value;
}

function render(numbers, table) {
  let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
  for (let x = 0; x < 9; ++x) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (var y = 0; y < 9; ++y) {
      let td = document.createElement('td');
      td.textContent = getNumberAt(numbers, x, y);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody);
}

// Example:
const numbers = new Array(9 * 9);
setNumberAt(numbers, 0, 0, 1);
setNumberAt(numbers, 0, 1, 2);
setNumberAt(numbers, 1, 0, 3);
setNumberAt(numbers, 8, 8, 9);
render(numbers, document.getElementById('sudoku'));
```

```css
#sudoku td {
  border: thin black solid;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
}

#sudoku td:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: thick black solid;
}

#sudoku tr:nth-child(3n) td {
  border-bottom: thick black solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="sudoku"></table>
```

Comment: That's a great answer thankyou! 
So numbers[] is an array with 81 entries that you reference with x and y values?
I'm not sure on your use of "=>", sorry.

Comment: @user3672543 The `f = x => y` arrow syntax allows defining functions pretty similar to `function f(x) { return y; }`. I changed the answer to standard function declarations for easier readability. The numbers[] array contains 81 entries. Entries 0-8 are the first row, entries 9-17 the second row, 18-26 the third row and so on. Given x and y, you can find the corresponding element in the flat array by evaluating x + y * 9.